# How to login with social account in Xamarin Forms without asking user to type in their password again?

Tags: authentication, xamarin.forms, social-authentication

I am using Xamarin.Auth to help user login to my app using their social account: google, facebook, twitter...
The problem is that it redirect to a login page and the user need to type in their password.
If the user already install the social app on their phone, I don't want them to type their password again because a lot of them don't even remember their password. How can I do it?
Sample code would be appreciate!

Comment: I tested on Facebook at least, user will not be prompted to enter the password if user is logged in in facebook app. It will directly ask for the permission to access the profile of the user. This is not related to Xamarin forms or App development. It depends on the third party authentication logic.